# How to handle submit button action in SKstoreviewcontroller ios

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I have implimented  SKStoreReviewController in My app. I just want to know how the functionality works. I need to satisfy below requirements.

I need to disply popup in all the 3 cases

1. For first 10 successful logins
2. After every 90 days
3. I don't want to disply rating popup never if he provide the rating.

How do I know if a user gave the rating and also I need to send
response to server if user gave the rating.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SKStoreReviewController submit button is active after your app is live in appStore. The submit button is automatically disable when you're running in debug mode. It's only active when you're launching your app in appStore. That is not mistake from apple or Xcode.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. I know that submit button will active when app installed from appstore, but i need to hit one api if user click on submit button how should I know that. Apple gave only one line of code. I need to know the click action of submit button.

Comment: There is no api for it.

Comment: I don't want any api,I need, how to handle the click action of that submit button

Comment: There is no action handler for it because it's fully managed by apple. If you can do it with other way. It'll reject from apple because you're deal with apple private api of SKStoreReviewController.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides some suggested [best practices](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/ratings-and-reviews/) and [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/requesting_app_store_reviews) for requesting reviews.

In answer to your requirements:

1. This is definitely not best practice; after 10 successful logins might be a reasonable time to ask for a review, but asking each time the user logs in will probably just be annoying.
2. Again, asking after 90 days is probably a reasonable interval.
3. By design there is no indication to your app as to whether the review request was shown, nor whether a review was left.

You can link directly to the App Store page where the user can provide a review, however you still have no indication of whether the user actually left a review or simply cancelled out of the web page.

The sample code I linked to shows how to track whether you have *requested* a review for the current version of your app. You cannot know whether the user has actually *reviewed* the current version.